# htaccess questions tagged as PHP

Tags: discussion

I find nearly every day, at least one question is posted relating to URL routing using .htaccess or mod rewrite.

Whether these questions belong here or not is another discussion, but why do so many people tag them as PHP?

Yes, they are usually routing to a index.php, but there is no actual PHP code involved.

Of course, you can do routing with PHP, but this questions are specifically about Apache level routing.

Comment: Why? Because people are confused.  The same thing happens in many tags - we get tons of users tagging `sql` questions with both `mysql` and `sql-server` because they are referring to `my-sql-server`.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, a lot of users don't create a mental separation between the components of their application's stack and the application itself. They may not have enough experience to know that mod_rewrite has applications outside PHP applications, for example. Or they may not be familiar with the way questions flow through Stack Overflow.

Tags are probably the most malleable component of any question. They are readily modified by users with edit privileges all the time.

Retag them and move on. There's nothing to worry about here, as the site relies on its community to fix these problems. Take on the responsibility to fix them when you find them -- that's what makes our community great. If the OP notices the question has been retagged, they may be more discerning next time. And if not, well, the community will retag the next question as well.

Comment: Yes, that is what I have been doing, which is why I noticed.

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea I've answered a lot of questions in those tags, and I read quite a lot more, and same as you, I retag them. It's certainly common, but I don't think of it as being endemic or harmful because it is so simple to fix.